# Merge Azure Logins

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I'm new to azure (used to "default" ASP.NET apps) and giving it some tries I learned that:
a.) it is very easy to add mobile logins (using FaceBook, Twitter, MS-Account...)
b.) that I can't see any database storing this data (user IDs an so)

My needs are the following:

- Enable users of a Win10 Universal / Mobile app to login with FB,... (works so far)
- use these users (via ID or so) to assign custom database entries to them (profile or so)
- assign (via some kind of management interface) the user to a role (for permissions)
- merge different logins (let the same user login with different providers=

To explain this imagine a forum (driven by apps (UWP, Android, ...)):

- The user logs in via Facebook.
- After (example) 10 moderated posts he will be able to write posts without moderation. (assign to role)
- Users can be manually added to roles (moderators)
- Last not least if the preferred service is not available (some corporate networks for an example restrict Facebook access) - the user shall be able to use (for an example) Google to login with "HIS account".

I understand that "merging" may need to be done while both providers are available.
Something like - "you are logged in with FB - to you want to add Google login to your account - if yes pleas additionally login with Google now while your are logged in with FB...

Two extra points:
 1. I don't want to have "username / password" (only social logins)
 2. I want to store the users email (for notification purposes)
--used from the social provider if available - or manually entered

Is this possible with "Azure Mobile" or would it be better to create a "Web App" and add (somehow) add "Mobile capabilities" (login, push notifications..) to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely do this.  The token information (which is equivalent to the claims that you request when you set up the authentication within the Authentication / Authorization Settings blade in the Azure Portal) is available on the /.auth/me endpoint of your app.  It's also available internally - for ASP.NET, that would be the [MobileAppUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt587413.aspx) class.  This is the IPrincipal for the request given an ASP.NET TableController decorated with the [Authorize] decorator.

You can adjust the information stored by the table controller.  There is some sample code commented out of the [FieldEngineer sample on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-fieldengineer/blob/master/server/FieldEngineer/Controllers/JobController.cs#L38) for this.

Comment: I can't see how to adjust the information stored by the Auth provider - I can't even see where this is stored. But anyhow - following your suggestion I would intercept the flow and store the data (available via ../me) in a different (my own) store. And for merging - I have to (at the point of the second login) the MobileAppUser and add the identity from the new login to his Identities - am I right?